# ASP .NET How Can I add a Script?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I have an issue adding a dynamic script in ASP .NET

I want to put the script in scriptText in ASP:ScriptManager, but when I run my app it doesn't work, somebody can help me?

This app is for make a chart with data from a Database, everything works fine when I read the data from data base and put it in scriptText, goes excellent, but I can't see the chart, if I put the code from chartsJS.org, it works fine.

PLZ Help!
Forward thanks!

I have this script

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<object> office = new List<object>();
    List<object> cantidad = new List<object>();
    List<object> labelCantidad = new List<object>();
    List<string> labels = new List<string>();
    DataTable tablaResultado = new DataTable();
    tablaResultado = Datos.AccesoDatos.ResumenOffice();
    if (tablaResultado.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (DataRow fila in tablaResultado.Rows)
        {
            labels.Add(fila[0].ToString());
            labelCantidad.Add(fila[1].ToString());
        }


    }
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    string scriptText = "";
    scriptText += "var ctx = document.getElementById(" + "resumen_office" + ").getContext('2d');";
    scriptText += "var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {";
    scriptText += "type: 'line',";
    scriptText += " data: {";
    foreach (object obj in labels)
    {
        sb.Append(string.Format("'{0}', ",obj));
    }
    scriptText += "labels: [" + sb + "]";
    scriptText += "datasets: [{";
    scriptText += "label: 'Microsoft Office',";
    StringBuilder objt = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (object obj in labelCantidad)
    {
        objt.Append(string.Format("{0}, ",Convert.ToInt32(obj)));
    }
    scriptText += "data: [" + objt + "]";
    scriptText += " backgroundColor: [";
    scriptText += "'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',";
    scriptText += "],";
    scriptText += "borderColor: [";
    scriptText += "'rgba(255,99,132,1)',";
    scriptText += "],";
    scriptText += "borderWidth: 1";
    scriptText += "}]";
    scriptText += "},";
    scriptText += "options: {";
    scriptText += "scales: {";
    scriptText += "yAxes: [{";
    scriptText += "ticks: {";
    scriptText += "beginAtZero: true";
    scriptText += "}";
    scriptText += "}]";
    scriptText += "}";
    scriptText += "}";
    scriptText += "});";
    scriptText += "</script>";
    grafico.CompositeScript.Path = scriptText;

}
```

This script is in tests.aspx.cs

In tests.aspx I have this

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="tests.aspx.cs" Inherits="tests" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="CPH" runat="Server">
<div class="container-fluid">
<canvas id="resumen_office"></canvas>
</div>

<asp:ScriptManager ID="grafico" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359558(v=vs.110).aspx) or [ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338357(v=vs.110).aspx) to register your script block on a page using the ScriptManager. For include scripts, use [ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptInclude](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360649(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the anwser Vladimir, can you show me an example? because I tried it but it didn't work too.

Comment: Thanks for the help I just put ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "grafico", scriptText, true); and it solved it!